# Using Isotope v2 with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, jquery-isotope

First question so please be nice!

I've been able to get Isotope working fine, but as soon as I try to use RequireJS to load it alongside jQuery, I can't seem to get it to work.

It's definitely loading the files because I can see them in the head of the dev toolbar, so the paths are fine. I'm stumped about what `isotopePkg` does, he even says it's undefined (???)

this is what my app.js looks like...

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery' : ['//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min', 
            'jquery-1.10.2.min'],
        'isotope' : 'isotope.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'isotope' : ['jquery']
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'isotope'], function(jQuery, Isotope) {

    jQuery('#container').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.element'
    });

});
```

Does anyone have a working example of what this code should look like, or have any ideas about where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a Fiddle? I set one up to reproduce what you showed here, and it works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/nate/Js5hL/

Comment: well blow me down, I wasn't expecting that! It must be something else then. I'm away for a few days so can't have a look right now, but I'll check it when I get back and post my findings. Thanks for having a look both.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue where requiring the isotope package on live environment was requesting for other modules. Please see the code below and link [isotope documentation](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/appendix.html#requirejs) for further instruction on how to implement isotope with requirejs.

I realize that answer is late but hopefully this might help anyone who come across this issue as well.

```
// require the require function
requirejs( [ 'require', 'jquery', 'path/to/isotope.pkgd.js' ],
  function( require, $, Isotope ) {
    // require jquery-bridget, it's included in isotope.pkgd.js
    require( [ 'jquery-bridget/jquery.bridget' ],
    function() {
      // make Isotope a jQuery plugin
      $.bridget( 'isotope', Isotope );
      // now you can use $().isotope()
      $('#container').isotope({...});
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: thanks for pointing this out... I need to learn to read docs :)

Comment: +1 for a good job on the answer.  However, when I see mangled code like that...I get leery of adding that into my production environment.  I wonder why they cant interact with RequireJS normally? Oh well...so much for Isotope.